# Setting window.top.location.href to a Form Submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, spring-mvc

I'm working on application which uses iframe overlays in addition to its main window. One of these overlays is used to modify user settings, some of which affect the display of the main window. So after saving these settings I would like to update the main window so that the user can see their new settings in action without having to log back into the application, but I have yet to find a way that is both consistent and renders the updated main window correctly...

The specifics are that a click on the Save button calls a JavaScript function. This function submits an HTML form to invoke the appropriate Spring-MVC action (saveXXXSettings.do). In the corresponding server-side method (saveXXXSettings()), a post-save call to another method to redraw the main page will render an updated version of that page but within the iframe overlay instead of the top frame of the browser. So I just tried to set window.top.location.href to the form submisssion, i.e.,

```
window.top.location.href = settingsForm.submit();
```

and got an HTTP error page with no helpful information. In looking at this site and the W3 School page, I see that the default method-type for HTML forms is GET, so I'm wondering if the only way to get around my error to use the corresponding Spring action and a parameter string, i.e.,

```
window.top.location.href = saveSettings.do?formParam1=xxxx&formParam2=yyyy
```

I'm trying to avoid having to assemble a parameter string just to achieve the window-refresh I want, so any advice or suggestions are appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using iframe event listeners instead. From the main frame add a listener to messages. Might look something like this...

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var submitParamters = e.data;
});
```

Then when the user clicks submit in the overlay iframe, post a message to the main window. Might look something like this...

```
mainWindow.postMessage(submitData, targetOrigin);
```

You can read more about this here... http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage.

This is capable of performing cross-domain messaging, but will work with same domain as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, CurtisJD, but I decided to go with a different approach: I'm copying the values entered in the iframe overlay into a form on the main page, then I submit that form to save the values then refresh the home page, which it does automatically at the top (i.e., browser) level. Thanks again for your quick response...